# How to float text around an image

Tags: html, css

I have created a demo of my issue, I am struggling with something so simple. I need to float text around an image within a div.

[Demo exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/aj9742ok/)

```
<div style="float:left; width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;">

    <div style="background-color: #f6f6f6; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 5px;">

        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg" height="300" style="padding: 0 10px 5px 0;"  />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat, urna eget convallis ullamcorper, felis ante viverra nunc, sed venenatis eros felis eu magna. Phasellus quis nisl et eros congue ornare. Proin aliquet commodo tincidunt. Morbi pharetra at libero id convallis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus eu pharetra nibh. Integer ultrices, ex vitae malesuada fringilla, odio arcu semper ante, nec interdum quam mi quis orci. Mauris gravida ut dolor quis bibendum. Vestibulum non cursus erat. Etiam convallis ex mattis, auctor velit sed, luctus leo. Nunc pharetra ligula dictum felis molestie porta. Vivamus volutpat odio id venenatis rutrum. Maecenas auctor turpis vel justo tristique, laoreet volutpat risus dictum.</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/j24uxyee/) There are many examples if you google something like "float text around image"

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of expected output?

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aj9742ok/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be below code will help you. Use this image instead.

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg" height="300" style="padding: 0 10px 5px 0; float:left;"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

recently found just such a piece can help

[shape](http://razvancaliman.com/writing/css-shapes-editor-chrome/)

or
add you img tag `float:left;`

```
element.style {
    float: left;/*add*/
    padding: 0 10px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the image adjacent to the div you want it to float next to and then give them float left + widths. For example:

```
<div>
    <img style="float: left; display: block; max-width: 50%;" />
    <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
        Some Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that we're using max-width on image here only to make sure it fits into the space available so that it floats next to the div.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of first div to 100% and use `float` css property with image if you do not want to compromise with image width

```
<div style="float:left; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;">

        <div style="background-color: #f6f6f6; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 5px;">

            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg"
            height="300" 
            style="padding: 0 10px 5px 0; float:right;"  />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque volutpat, urna eget convallis ullamcorper, felis ante viverra nunc, sed venenatis eros felis eu magna. Phasellus quis nisl et eros congue ornare. Proin aliquet commodo tincidunt. Morbi pharetra at libero id convallis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus eu pharetra nibh. Integer ultrices, ex vitae malesuada fringilla, odio arcu semper ante, nec interdum quam mi quis orci. Mauris gravida ut dolor quis bibendum. Vestibulum non cursus erat. Etiam convallis ex mattis, auctor velit sed, luctus leo. Nunc pharetra ligula dictum felis molestie porta. Vivamus volutpat odio id venenatis rutrum. Maecenas auctor turpis vel justo tristique, laoreet volutpat risus dictum.

        </div>        
 </div>
```